# Jquery function to change background image every 5 seconds not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following function in jquery:

```
window.onload = function() {

    $(function () {
        var images = ["banner.png", "banner2.png"];
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            i++;
            if (i == images.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            $("#banner").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).css("background", "url(../media/img/" + images[i] + ") no-repeat");
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

I want it to change background every 5 seconds,
however it changes to a an empty background, here's the CSS code:

```
#banner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../media/img/banner.png) no-repeat;
    height: 628px;
```

Just for the record I do have a banner2.png in my file, I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX right, mistook it for a function, thanks!

Comment: @Warden330 was right. The background rule must be like :  `background: url('my/url/image.png')` the url has to be inside quotes.

Comment: Could it be that the iteration is 1 value to far? It should be picture 0 and 1 cause its an array, and like this it is i == length which is 2 but picture 2 doesnt exist?

Comment: getting any console errors? and what is happening in the frontend, do you see the css background you set from javascript being applied?

Comment: @JaromandaX I didnt say that the quotes are the problem.I just mentioned [The right pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) for background property.

Comment: CSS takes it with and without quotes, the issue is probably the url like @JaromandaX said

Comment: @JaromandaX then what was the reason to   mark Warden330 comment as   wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Relative CSS paths can be tricky (this has tripped me up more times than I care to admit)

In a CSS file, the path is relative to that CSS file

When setting it through javascript, it's relative to the HTML file of the page

So, if your folder layout is like

```
root
|- css
|   |- style.css
|
|- media
|   | - banner.jpg
|   | - banner1.jpg
|
|- index.html
```

Then the CSS would reference the banner.jpg as `../media/banner.jpg`

But when setting the background from javascript in index.html ... the path is `./media/banner.jpg` or even `media/banner.jpg`

So

```
$(this).css("background", "url(./media/img/" + images[i] + ") no-repeat");
```

or

```
$(this).css("background", "url(media/img/" + images[i] + ") no-repeat");
```

Or (I think a little easier to read - but not available in Internet Explorer) using template strings (i.e. in backticks ``) - also, just change `background-image` since the `no-repeat` is in the original CSS

```
$(this).css("background-image", `url(media/img/${images[i]})`);
```

You can even use the `"` that seem to be not-required, but shown everywhere `background-image` is documented

```
$(this).css("background-image", `url("media/img/${images[i]}")`);
```

Although, I think that is less readable (❁´◡`❁)

Comment: @Baitalon - I guess a visual was required  as that is what I'd been saying in the comments :p